# two different versions of a codebase, one heavily commented and one with zero (or minimal) comments

Tags: git, comments, dvcs

If you have a project where the only difference in the 2 branches are the comments, what is a good workflow (assuming Git, but other ideas are welcome):

- simply write a hook that strips out comments after each commit and saves the result to a set of files, use only a single branch
- simply maintain 2 branches
- other

Comment: Why would you strip out comments?

Comment: I was simply trying to keep the question simple. In reality I would want to strip out only those comments that are not needed by the documentation generator.

Comment: @Neil, to "obfuscate" javascript published on a website?  To comply with an open-source license but really show nothing?

Comment: if you want to exclude them from documentation, keep them in a format that document generator will ignore. I've been maintaining two parallel codebases for past 3 weeks. NEVER AGAIN!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends why you need the branch with no comments.  If it is only to release to someone (or something) periodically, then I would go with the hook-script approach.

I can't see why you would have anyone working on the uncommented version if comments are available.  Stripping them in a script on-demand therefore seems preferable to maintaining a branch with comments stripped (which would no doubt cause headaches on integration).

Comment: Depending on the comments, it may be preferable to work only with the uncommented branch.

Answer (score 1):

If one version has no comments, then by all means - it would be best to strip them automatically (but at the retrieval stage, not the commit). Otherwise, either merge them or keep two branches.

Comment: As Neil said, why would you want to strip out comments?